# Where does that "selectedSubreddit" come from in Redux Reddit API example

Tags: redux, react-redux

All:

I am pretty new to Redux, when I follow its Reddit API example, there is one code snippet confuse me so much:

In AsyncApp.js, there is:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props
    dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(selectedSubreddit))
  }
```

I wonder where the dispatch and selectedSubreddit get bind to this.props?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example is using the `connect()` function from [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) to inject certain parts of the Redux state and the store's `dispatch()` function as props in that component. See the ['Usage With React' part of the Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) for more information.

For example:

***App.js:***

```
export class App extends Component {
  //...
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { selectedReddit, postsByReddit } = state
  const {
    isFetching,
    lastUpdated,
    items: posts
  } = postsByReddit[selectedReddit] || {
    isFetching: true,
    items: []
  }

  return {
    selectedReddit,
    posts,
    isFetching,
    lastUpdated
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

The `connect()` function here is taking the `mapStateToProps()` function above to inject the appropriate parts of the Redux state as props in the `<App />` component. The keys of the object returned by `mapStateToProps()` correspond to the names of the props injected, and the corresponding values are the values of those injected props.

`connect()` can also take a second argument, `matchDispatchToProps()`, which can be used to inject specific action dispatch functions as props in your component. Whether or not you supply any arguments to `connect()`, it will inject your Redux store's `dispatch()` function as a prop called `dispatch`.

These connected container components receive state updates from the store, so when your Redux state changes, the connected container components will receive new props accordingly.